# loop on attributes to create inventory variations

Tags: php, arrays, inventory

I have this array of attributes for example:

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [title] => Brown
            [parent_id] => 1
            [parent_title] => Color
            [isMultiple] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21
            [title] => Cream
            [parent_id] => 1
            [parent_title] => Color
            [isMultiple] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 61
            [title] => S
            [parent_id] => 2
            [parent_title] => Size
            [isMultiple] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 62
            [title] => M
            [parent_id] => 2
            [parent_title] => Size
            [isMultiple] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 63
            [title] => L
            [parent_id] => 2
            [parent_title] => Size
            [isMultiple] => 1
        )

)
```

from this array we can understand that we have 6 variations of inventory:

```
1 | Brown | S
2 | Brown | M
3 | Brown | L
4 | Cream | S
5 | Cream | M
6 | Cream | L
```

1. What is the correct way to loop over this array to create another array of the 6 variations like in the above example.
2. let's assume that I have another 2 attrs in the array like this:

   ```
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 64
            [title] => Cotton
            [parent_id] => 3
            [parent_title] => Metiral
            [isMultiple] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 65
            [title] => Wool
            [parent_id] => 3
            [parent_title] => Metiral
            [isMultiple] => 1
        )
   ```

How I can loop on this array to create variations like these:

```
1 | Brown | S | wool
2 | Brown | S | cotton
3 | Brown | M | wool
4 | Brown | M | cotton
5 | Brown | L | wool
6 | Brown | L | cotton
7 | Cream | S | wool
8 | Cream | S | cotton
9 | Cream | M | wool
10 | Cream| M | cotton
11 | Cream| L | wool
12 | Cream| L | cotton
```

Answer (score 1):

OK I found the solution:

A. right, I made an associative arrays of all my attributes:

Array
(

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 20
        [1] => 21
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 61
        [1] => 62
        [2] => 63
    )
```

)

B. then I recursively create the whole possible variations:

```
function buildVariants($arrays, $i = 0) {
if (!isset($arrays[$i])) {
    return array();
}
if ($i == count($arrays) - 1) {
    return $arrays[$i];
}

// get combinations from subsequent arrays
$tmp = $this->buildVariants($arrays, $i + 1);

$result = array();

// concat each array from tmp with each element from $arrays[$i]
foreach ($arrays[$i] as $v) {
    foreach ($tmp as $t) {
    $result[] = is_array($t) ? array_merge(array($v), $t) : array($v, $t);
    }
}

return $result;
}
```

C. then I add it to tables in this structure:

[See tables stru](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144200/designing-a-sql-schema-for-a-combination-of-many-to-many-relationship-variation)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start with "cleaning" your data first:

```
$attr = array();

foreach( $attributes as $attribute ){
  $attr[$attribute['parent_title']][] = $attribute['title'];
}
```

So that you have something like

```
array(
  "Color" => array(
    "Color1",
    "Color2",
    "Color3"
  ),
  "Size" => array(
    "Size1",
    "Size2",
    "Size3"
  ),
  //...
);
```

From there on this should be helpful:
[How to generate in PHP all combinations of items in multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567082/how-to-generate-in-php-all-combinations-of-items-in-multiple-arrays)