# Data model for products with attributes, with different prices for each attributes combination

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am developing a generic e-commerce solution using a relational database (MySQL), and I want to manage products like this:

- Each **product** (e.g. *wood*, *plastic*, *steel*) will have several **attributes** (e.g. *thickness*, *width*, *height*, *color*).
- In turn, each **attribute** can have several **values** (e.g. *3 mm* or *5 mm* for thickness, *blue* or *red* for color, etc.), **which have a different price in each case**.

So far so good, my current approach counts on 4 tables:

- products (**id**, name, desc)
- attributes (**id**, name, desc, type)
- attribute_values (**id**, *attribute_id*, value)
- attribute_product (**attribute_id**, **product_id**, price)

With this data model, I can combine products and attributes well, for example:

- Define a **product** called `wood` which have 2 **attributes** (`thickness` and `height`) which in turn have `3 mm` and `5 mm` options for thickness and `blue` and `red` options for color...

The problem comes with **price calculation** because if I declare **price** in *attribute_product* pivot table, I still do not know which value is selected for that specific attribute and product.

How could I modify the data model to be able to somehow '*link*' products with attribute values?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide some data sample and expected result set

Answer (score 1):

Right, a linking table like attribute_product only link 1 instance to 1 instance, and your products can have multiple attributes, so that model doesn't work.

What you are calling the attribute_product is what most people would say is the product. It is the thing that has a price. So I would just call that "products". What you are calling products are perhaps product_categories.

So  the attribute tables would be child tables to it.

- product_categories (id, desc) -- eg. "Wood"
- products (id, name, desc, category_id, price) -- eg. "Wood: 3x5mm Red"
- attributes (id, name, desc, type)  -- eg. "thickness"
- product_attributes (id, product_id, attribute_id, value) -- multiple rows per product; eg. "3mm" "red"

Comment: Thank you for the response.
Your schema looks similar to the one proposed by @DenisdeBernardy here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144200/designing-a-sql-schema-for-a-combination-of-many-to-many-relationship-variation... but both of you place the `price` field right in `products` table (or SKUs table). In my case, the **price must be dynamically generated from the attributes** because I have options that are filled by customers themselves (e.g., an open number field with width or height...). In this case, I can not create a line for each possible width value... Any ideas?

Comment: In other words, what if `attributes` are not limited to only several options and can be user inputted to fully customise their products?

Comment: So would there be a price for Wood, plus an additional amount for 3mm, etc?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. The customer will customise the product with, e.g., `thickness` (choosing from several available values from a dropdown), but also will specify the `width` manually (through a number input) and so on... And so the price should be dynamically generated from all attributes. Thanks in advance Jon.

Comment: It sounds like each product and attribute_value has it's own price, which you want to sum to get the total charge? If so you could add a price field to both your products and attribute_values tables. The linking and summing would happen in the invoice. You might need a detail table in the invoice for the attribute values for the same selected product.

Comment: Thanks, all of your answers conform a very good starting point :)