# How to Structure Tables for Product Variation with MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, database-design

I need help with **Product Variations**. I haven't started anything yet, so I don't have an example because I don't know where to start. I will make a small sketch of what I think it should look like, and anyone who has experience with this category would help me a lot.

Database structure:

**Color**

```
|   id   |   Color Name   |   Product ID   |
|    1   |     White      |        1       |
|    2   |     Black      |        1       |
```

**Size**

```
|   id   |   Size Name   |   Product ID   |
|    1   |     XXXL      |        1       |
|    2   |     M         |        1       |
```

**Product**

```
|   id   |   Product Name   |   Product Size   |   Product Color   |   Product Description
|    1   |   Jacket         |        1,2       |        1,2        |     Jacket.....
```

Because I have never done product variation before, I want to get information on whether this method is correct or not? Share with me your opinions, and experiences on how to do it in the best possible way

Comment: This is a good [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19200349/231316), along with most answers in that thread, and the ones that talk about SKUs

Comment: Most of the taggings and technologies mentioned here are unrelated. This is essentially a db schema question, right? I added `group-by` as a tag as well because you'd want to do that but there's no PHP nor PDO relation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a mixture of columns and JSON.

The columns should be items that are typically searched on.  Index the columns.

The JSON column contains the less common attributes -- For example, only dresses have a "dress size", only cameras have an "F-stop".

Have MySQL search on columns; have the app finish the filtering by checking the JSON.

More:  [*Entity-Attribute-Value*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav)